# GCSE: volume of cylinder( How I can find the same height of the container)

Tags: geometry

Looking please for any help.

In the figure below, 2 containers are given. Pour water from container A into container B until the height in both containers is the same. Find the same height in both container.

My attempt was the following:
6:4
6,5:x
6x= 26
x=4,3

I know I messed up!
All help/solutions appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total volume is $\pi (6)^2 (6.5)$. Suppose the common height is $h$. Then, $$\pi(6)^2 h + \pi(4)^2 h = \pi (6)^2 (6.5) \\ h = \frac{36\times 6.5}{52}=4.5 \ cm$$

Comment: Thank you so much